# Can I transfer money to another player on GTA V online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

I would like to know if it is possible if I can share some money on GTAV online with my sister, but we play on the same console, is it possible to transfer it through to her some how?

Answer (score 1):

You can share money from jobs, you can give certain people more money on heists you setup. But directly giving money to her bank account is not possible.

Comment: unless you plan on letting them kill you repeatedly... which is a slow process.

Comment: @AlexSpencer Yeah but it seams they are running on the same system, which means they aren't playing together at the same time.

Comment: Ah yeah didnt pick up on that. Makes the process even slower. stops it entirely in fact. Also didn't i comment on you earlier...?